# Drawer Slide not working after changing from LTR to RTL in React Native (iOS)

Tags: ios, react-native, navigation-drawer, arabic-support

In my React Native app, I have to change my layout from LTR to RTL when choosing Arabic language.

I did that by

```
I18nManager.forceRTL(true);
RNRestart.Restart();
```

After the app restarts the drawer slider does not seem to be working.Although it will start to work once I refresh or kill the app. This only happens in iOS.

Has anyone experienced this? Please let me know of any solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is the upgrade to the latest @react-navigation/drawer version.